# Is it possible to attach artifacts in an email notification in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

We have a plan that produces an executable artifact. Is there a way to tell bamboo to email those artifacts as attachments in a build notification? For the record we're using atlassian on-demand.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a email from a bash script using `sendmail` here is a quick [tutorial](https://ariejan.net/2007/06/10/send-mail-with-a-bash-shell-script). You can then just include the `artifact` link in the email

Answer (score 1):

No wonder Bamboo still didn't have this fixed and we are in 2019 and this request was from 2013. We do have a html report that we want to send along with Notification email from Bamboo.

But we were told its not possible in Bamboo. So we came up with a final task in our build which runs a powershell script that sends email with the html report we generate.

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.yourcompanydomain.com -Port 25 -To $toEmail -From $fromEmail -Subject $subject -Body $message -BodyAsHtml -Attachments report.html -Credential $mycreds
```

You have to declare variables like  $toEmail, like
$toEmail = "abc@xyx.com"
$mycreds = credentials for account from which you are sending